# Is there a standard method for choosing features from different feature selection techniques?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I have four different feature selection techniques, Backwards Elimination, Lasso, feature_importances, and Recursive feature selection. Each technique returns slightly different results. For example,

- **Backwards Elimination**: Spread Direction
- **Lasso**: Spread Move, and Spread
- **Feature_Importances_**: Spread Percentage and Spread Money
- **Recursive**: Spread Money

is there a standard method when choosing features from different models? Should you choose the features that each model returns or is there a preferred method when doing this?

[image]

Comment: can you provide details of your data?

Comment: @imtiazulHassan I added a sample from my training data which contains a little over 8k rows

Comment: It depends on the method: Linear models will probably work best with a different set of features when compared to tree based. Please elaborate on the methods

Comment: @Peter I'm using a random forest model

Comment: It is good that you are getting similar results from all 4 methods.  That is a good way to perform feature selection. There will never be an exact matchup of variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way. It depends on the goal of feature selection.

One useful method is cross-validation. If the evaluation metric score improves during cross-validation, then removing the feature improves the predictive ability of the model.